# Cisco: Return key needed after remote ssh console access using rotaries

Tags: cisco, ssh, tacacs

I´m configuring a remote ssh access with TACACS to a console in a Cisco 2911, on a rotary port. When the access is granted after a successful ssh authentication, an Return key is needed to access the new authentication in the machine on the console line of the rotary. 
Is there any way to avoid that Return key?
Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a command for this: **autoselect**

It´s explained in Cisco docs: 
[Cisco Help](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/dial/configuration/guide/15_0s/dia_15_0s_book/dia_cfg_asyn_lns_int.pdf)

*The autoselect command bypasses the login prompt and enables the specified session to begin automatically. However, when the autoselect command is entered with the during login keyword, the username or password prompt appears **without the need to press the Return key**; thus “login” users will 
get a prompt right away without needing to press the Return key. While the username or password 
prompt is displayed, you can choose either to answer these prompts or to send packets from an 
autoselected protocol.*

Comment: You should accept your own answer whenever you can. :-)